# Wheatstone bridge and difference op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, wheatstone-bridge

I use Wheatstone bridge as a dual voltage divider to feed both inverting and non-inverting inputs of differential op-amp:
[image]
Theoretically voltage can be calculated using voltage divider expression: Va = V1*(R2/(R2+R1) = 7.5 mV. Following the same reasoning Vb = 6.0 mV. When I use LTSpice to calculate these voltages for the bridge alone without op-amp, everything is fine. However, when I connect bridge to op-amp circuit, Va = 6.5 mV and Vb = 4.8 mV. If LTSpice doesn't give erroneous results, how should I calculate voltages Va and Vb?

Comment: The voltages at Wheatstone bridge are correct when you **do not load** the points Va and Vb. You then add the opamp + circuit. Are points Va and Vb still unloaded or does the opamp + circuit draw some current?

Comment: R1,2,3,4 are unbalanced and too high relative to R5,6,7,8 and thus  affects the gain of + and -ve signals with different gains.  The DIff AMP impedance must use an INA (instr. Amp) for these values to be insensitive to source impedance.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, it is an exercise from a textbook. Theoretically op-amp input current is 0.

Comment: *it is an exercise from a textbook* That doesn't mean anything to me, what if the textbook shows a circuit with unexpected behavior to teach you how that affects the circuit's behavior. Never assume that a circuit "must work" because it is in a book. *Theoretically op-amp input current is 0.* I was not assuming that there was current flowing into the opamp's inputs. How about the current through R5, R6, R7 and R8 ? Are they zero? Why / why not ? Look at the circuit and **THINK** what happens when R5, R6, R7, R8 + opamp are there and when the're not.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, I(R8):  -4.83844e-008 A, I(R7): -4.83921e-008 A, I(R6): -1.31965e-007 A, I(R5): -1.31973e-007 A. These currents definitely are not 0, because I have a current from voltage source which flows through bridge, R5 and R6 to output terminal of op-amp.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, I understand what you are talking about. Since I have a load (op-amp + circuit), it draws a current from points A and B of the bridge. But in order to calculate the value of the current through R5, I must know the voltage at non-inverting input. In order to know this voltage, I have to know the voltage near R7. This volatge can be calculated only if I know the voltage at point B of the bridge. Thus I go back to the starting point.

Comment: Recalculate Vb with the knowledge that R4 is now in parallel with 100 kohm (R7 + R8). Then calculate the voltage at the junction of R7 and R8 and you have your answer.

Comment: @Andy aka, it works, but only for Vb. I could avoid this problem if I draw the common ground for the whole circuit. As it is drawn in the textbook, it's not obvious this is a parallel branch to R4. However, what is the solution for Va?

Comment: The voltage to the right of R5 must be 80% of Vb. So, to calculate Va you use R1, R2 and R5 going to 80% of Vb.

Comment: @tenghiz Always start by assuming OA input current must be zero and output must not be saturated, therefore the input voltages are always the same (if witching the CM range). In this case they are clearly not balanced and the source Req cct. Adds to Rin which affects voltage divider to Vin , so read-read my 1st comment then balance the bridge or determine the offset as the signal.

Comment: That is why the instrumentation amplifier was invented...

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Andy aka for the hint.

Also, it would be useful to draw a common ground for the whole circuit. 
[image]
In this case it would be obvious that R4 is in parallel with (R7 + R8). The Thévenin resistance for this branch is 37.5 kOhm and Vb = 4.8 Ohm. Then the voltage between R7 and R8 is 3.84 V. According to ideal op-amp model, the same volatge is between R5 and R7.
[image]
Now we can calculate Va: (Vs - Va)/20k = Va/30k + (Va - 3.84)/20k. ==> Va = 6.5 V.